# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (624,3) while doing weighted predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, keras, scikit-learn

I am doing an ensemble of predicted probabilities from seven models. Each model outputs three classes. I calculated the weights in prior to be given for the predictions from each of the seven models.These predicted weights are stored in the variable "prediction_weights". The weighted averaging code is given below:

```
prediction_weights = np.array([[3.66963025e-01, 1.08053256e-01,1.14617370e-01, 4.10366349e-01,
 6.16391075e-14, 4.37376684e-14, 9.26785075e-18]]) 
weighted_predictions7 = np.zeros((nb_test_samples, num_classes), 
                                dtype='float32')
for weight, prediction in zip(prediction_weights, preds):
    weighted_predictions7 += weight * prediction    
yPred7 = np.argmax(weighted_predictions7, axis=1)
yTrue = Y_test.argmax(axis=-1)
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(yTrue, yPred7) * 100

np.savetxt('weighted_averaging_7_y_pred.csv',
            weighted_predictions7,fmt='%f',
            delimiter = ",")
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-8f3a15c0fec1>", line 2, in <module>
    weighted_predictions7 += weight * prediction

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (624,3)
```

The following are the shapes of the variables:

```
    prediction_weights: (1,7) - Array of Float 64
    nb_test_samples: 1 - int
    num_classes: 1 - int
    weighted_predictions7: (624,3) - Array of float32
    Y_test: (624,3) - Array of float32
    yTrue: (624,) - Array of Int64
```

Comment: If `weight` and `prediction` are numpy arrays, then the line throwing your error is trying to do element-wise multiplication between those arrays. However, they are different shapes and it does not know how to interpret execution. You'll need to determine how you want that multiplication to take place and handle it more explicitly, or make the two arrays match shapes.

Comment: I get the impression that your question is really about determining what the dimensions of various pieces of data should be in order for the system to make sense theoretically, rather than anything to do with the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replacing

```
prediction_weights = np.array([[3.66963025e-01, 1.08053256e-01,1.14617370e-01, 4.10366349e-01,
 6.16391075e-14, 4.37376684e-14, 9.26785075e-18]])
```

by

```
prediction_weights = [3.66963025e-01, 1.08053256e-01,1.14617370e-01, 4.10366349e-01,
 6.16391075e-14, 4.37376684e-14, 9.26785075e-18]
```

resolved the error.